# Exporting huge Google Sheet to a PDF

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a google sheet having 110,000 rows and 10 columns.

If I try to export using the normal File > Download > As PDF, it takes forever to make the Save button work (The ~4800 pages of the PDF keeps rendering and on a premature save, nothing happens) I have done this on Chrome, Firefox and Edge browser, just to see if changing browser would make a difference.

Then I tried using app-script, but the ones available on the WebApp StackExchange did not work.

I know the solution will be with an app script code. What is the best solution for me to able to export the 1 million cell sized sheet to a PDF easily.

**EDIT:**

As per the comments below I did execute the 8 line code in the newer app script console of Google,

```
function saveAsPDF() {
const folderName = `Cubing`;
const fileNamePrefix = `filename`;

DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName)
.next()
.createFile(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
              .getBlob()
              .getAs(`application/pdf`)
              .setName(`${fileNamePrefix} - ${Utilities.formatDate(new 
 Date(), `GMT-8`, `yyyy-MM-dd`)}`));  
 }
```

But I got a message which is not related to the code.

The execution log said,

```
Exception: We're sorry, no servers are currently available. Please wait a bit and try again.
saveAsPDF   @ Code.gs:7
```

Comment: I tried to run the scripts discussed in the thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997924/export-or-print-with-a-google-script-new-version-of-google-spreadsheets-to-pdf

Comment: Please be more descriptive. Do you get error messages on all the scripts? (please edit the question and add the textual error message, I suggest you to focus on one of the scripts)

Comment: The author's credentials of those scripts are impeccable and I agree with focusing/troubleshooting on _one_ of those scripts. But at the risk of mudding the waters, the scripts date from 2014/2015 and Apps Script has changed a lot. A fast Google (only results in the 'last year') raised [Can google sheets save a PDF copy onto a selected Drive folder nightly?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/62724243?hl=en&msgid=62916337); just eight lines of code, and it works nicely. Whether it suits you is another matter but I would like to see you using more recent precedents. @Rubén may have a view.

Comment: The 8-line code is not executed due to a weird execution error with the new editor (I tried to execute with the old google editor too.) It is an issue with SaveAsPDF object I guess. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761058

Comment: In my (limited) experience, this is a "there's-an-error-somewhere" kind of error; however it is giving you a big hint here: "@ Code.gs:7". The values of your variables (`const folderName`, `const fileNamePrefix` and `const fileNamePrefix`) are are defined between backticks rather than single (or double) quotes. Also `.setName(`${fileNamePrefix} - ${Utilities.formatDate(new  Date(), `GMT-8`, `yyyy-MM-dd`)}`));` contains more backticks and is presenting as two lines rather than one long line. Try those changes and see what happens.

Comment: @Tedinoz I suggest you to post this kind of comments as answers (even if another user, including me, posted an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `` ` `` pair-matching problem:

```
1
|
v
`${fileNamePrefix} - ${Utilities.formatDate(new 
 Date(), `GMT-8`, `yyyy-MM-dd`)}`
         ^     ^  ^          ^  ^
         |     |  |          |  |
         1     2  2          3  3
```

While there are multiple ways to fix your script,  what about this (use the `+` to concatenate values and regular strings instead of template literals):

```
fileNamePrefix + ' - ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-8', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals